# AdMob integration in flash .apk using AS3 adobe CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, admob, adobe, ane

I would like to ask you all can someon explain me AdMob addition to flash project using CS6 with AS3. I have allready in project, and by the time i finish it i would love to put some AdMob on it. I did Search for ANE and simillar thing, but i just cant figure it out what end where to edit. Which file to put where etc.

Thank you

Comment: @LasVegasCoder maybe you could help on this, now i really cant figure it out on my own. Last one was easiest ;)

Comment: The answer is totally googlable. Google > flash cs6 ane. The first link is not just relevant, it's the official documentation: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/using-ane-in-flash.html Moreover, it even contains the link to exact instructions for exactly **AdMob**.

Comment: @Organis and u mean i have to use Milkmans Ane for 30$ and thats final solution? hm...i hope someone expirienced will teach me what to look, anything about those script files...i manage to add those ane and swc files to project and add script file which is refering to it, but then my video preview wouldnt start. if u have patirnce for me pls respond here

Comment: A quick google search reveals a free recently built ANE for AIR > 21. https://github.com/pozirk/ANEAdMob

Comment: Yes, i got this ANE, but as soon i put those files into the project, and i can put those lines inside <manifest> , i dont Know what next. I Know i edit app_xml file with those lines, but what with the lines from example. Where to put those and where to use my AdMob ID

Comment: Not exactly clear, what you're having problem with. You don't know how to build APK? You don't know what to do with this ANE? Something else?

Comment: @Organis I did build an APK. I did download ANE, put it in folder with both my files from aok, .fla and .xml file. I did add .ane and .swc files to project like instructed. And thats where my story ends. I dont Know from now on, which codes to put where. What to copy in which file and where. And i Know i have to put my AdMob ID somewhere and to put all this orders for AdMob to be functional but havgot no clue. By the way, when i did put .ane and .swc files to project, when i hit ctrl+enter for testing movie, it couldnt be tested for some reason it says movie cant play

Comment: Tutorials? https://github.com/lancelot1/ane-admob/tree/master/demo/src

Comment: So lets make something clear for me...this as file i put as class to whole project...i know that. Xml file i put into my xml file...copy paste as needed...but where to put and what is necesery from all this to have only single bottom banner...i know some things ..but yet cant figure out what to do with them. I know how to find tutorials...but i dont get where to handle those. And is there any way to test this except ctrl+enter...because when i hit this wont play

Comment: Can i just copy singlebanner.as and set it to project as class...and put ane and swc files to project and thats it? Where to put AdMob publisher id?

Comment: @Organis where to add stuff and which one from singlebanner.xml. As i understood, i copy paste some of the content in my app_app.xml, and i add singlebanner.as to class of my project? am i right?

Comment: I did see all the tutorials...and on last link i didnt find any just files. But i dont know what to do with that ANE files for AdMob and all those codes wherw to put them. Cann someone just point me in right direction with some clues if u dont want to tell me all? Pls